# Get latest source code in TFS Visual Studio

Tags: tfs

I'm new to TFS. So, I have downloaded a source code from TFS last year. Recently, my team has made changes to the code, how do I get the latest source code that has been edited by my team. I'm confused between these two "Check Out" and "Get Latest Version".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want "Get Latest Version".

To "Check out" a file or folder is to lock the file and prevent other people from changing those files - like how you "check out" a book from a library (other people can't use that book when you have it).

Compared to `git` where a "checkout" means to "switch my working folder tree to this commit".

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I have tried "Get Latest Version" but it seems like I didn't see any changes and when I check the "Last Check In" column, it was checked in last 2016. So, I'm not sure, if I did the right thing and is it possible to check which code has been made changes?

Comment: @Angelyn If it says the "Last check in" was in 2016 then no changes have been made. If other users are claiming that they've made changes then it's possible that you (or them) are in Offline Mode - or they checked-in their changes to a different TFS Branch. Speak to your TFS Server's administrator to find out what's going on.